# Why different font rendering with graphics.drawString() and a default JLabel with ClearType?

Tags: java, fonts, drawstring, cleartype

Why has the displayed GUI different font style/rendering with `graphics.drawString()` and a default JLabel with activated cleartype? And how can i fix it?

[image: Image to show the differents]

Comment: It is probably related to the options used to render the string.  Try some alternatives using the source on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444869/how-do-i-read-pixels-from-a-png-file-in-java/6445283#6445283).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;    
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);

g2d.setFont(font);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.drawString("Hello World", 25, 100);
```

Comment: Note that although the proposed solution makes font rendering a bit better (or at least _different_) it is not turning on cleartype but only font antialiasing. Font antialiasing uses gray translucent pixels and give good picture on CRT displays. Cleartype uses translucent R and B pixels to give a sub-pixel preceived resolution on TFT displays. The TFTs may have different subpixel ordering, hence you can never get the same quality as JLabel. Except, if you subclass a JLabel (or a Graphics content initialized by Swing) and extract _all_ the antialiasing settings in place for your later use.