# Opencv always matching template?

Tags: java, image, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to identify pokémon. At first I thought about image-recognition, but then I realized it wasn't necessary since I could compare the screenshot of a pokémon with the actual sprites of the game (which are almost identical). So, I came across opencv. 
I check if the screenshot of the pokémon I want to identify is a match with the template image (sprite of the actual game).

[Screenshot Pokémon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbclf.jpg)

[Template n. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBto0.jpg) ==> [Template Match n.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSSBG.jpg)

[Template n. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J1Qt.jpg) ==> [Template Match n. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpgO4.jpg)

As you can see both templates are a match when instead only Template n. 2 should be a match. Basically, doesn't matter what template I choose, it's always a match. What I am doing wrong?

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(inFile);
Mat templ = Imgcodecs.imread(templateFile);

//Create the result matrix
int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

//Do the Matching and Normalize
Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

//Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

Point matchLoc;
if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
    matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
} else {
    matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
}

System.out.println("minLoc: "+mmr.minLoc);
System.out.println("maxLoc: "+mmr.maxLoc);
System.out.println("minVal: "+mmr.minVal);
System.out.println("maxVal: "+mmr.maxVal);

//Detection rectangle
Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
        matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

//Save the visualized detection
Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, img);
```

Edit:

I just printed minLoc, maxLoc, minVal, maxVal in order to understand how to set the threshold.

```
templatematch1.png
minLoc: {79.0, 101.0}
maxLoc: {0.0, 5.0}
minVal: 0.0
maxVal: 1.0


templatematch2.png
minLoc: {80.0, 106.0}
maxLoc: {17.0, 0.0}
minVal: 0.0
maxVal: 1.0
```

Comment: you never set a threshold on the match value (min or max)... what do you expect? You should see match for #2 higher (or lower) than for #1

Comment: also you need the same background to have a decent detection... You'd probably better with descriptor matching

Comment: I've just updated the question. As you can see, minVal and maxVal are the same for both #1 and #2. So, not sure how I should set the threshold.

Comment: you are normalizing the result... obviously min and max will always be 0 and 1

Comment: Thank you. I will check if the minVal is < of the threeshold. I guess I need to set its value experimentally? Hopefully it will be the correct match on all pokémon.

Regarding the descriptor matching, I have no idea on how to do it. I am a newbie in computer vision.