# Read pattern from colored png layout image into array?

Tags: java, arrays, bitmap

[image: layout]

```
#FFFFFF = 0 = black background
#FF0000 = 1 = corner, rotated through 0° https://i.imgur.com/8H5PL63.png
#FF8000 = 2 = corner, rotated through 90°
#FFFF00 = 3 = corner, rotated through 180°
#80FF00 = 4 = corner, rotated through 270°
#00FF00 = 5 = pipe, rotated through 0° https://i.imgur.com/UA2z1QZ.png
#00FF80 = 6 = pipe, rotated through 90°
```

So I want to read the image and automatically fill my `int[][] layout` array with `0-6`. The complete image is `896(w) x 992(h)` and every tile is `32x32 pixels` big.

There is a 1px border on every tile, so the color is `30x30 pixels` big.
[image]

This is my java code until now (only the `Grid.class`):

```
public class Grid {
private static int[][] layout;

public Grid() {
    layout = new int[][]{ //28x31
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//5
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//10
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//15
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//20
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//25
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//30
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
}
```

}

Comment: You can also initialize the array as `layout = new int[28][31];` without the lot of 0s. What is the exact question/problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution step-by-step:

1. Study the following [**commands**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444869/how-do-i-read-pixels-from-a-png-file):

   `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("filename.png"));`
   `java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y);`
2. Load and read from that picture. The best would be to get a color from every 16th pixel (having 32x32 tiles - so read from the middle of a tile is safe).
3. Compare if a color matches with one from your pattern.
4. If it matches out, write to your `layout[i][j]` array.
5. Repeat the cycle until you reach the end of a picuture. (Don't forget to `i++;` and `j++;` in the end of a cycle.
6. You have a result. Just looping through **28x31** array are 868 operations, so don't worry about speed.

Comment: That is great! I searched for exactly this `getRGB(int x, int y)`!! Thank you :)