# bytes per pixel, bytes per line - How to use function nativeSetImageBytes in tessbaseapi.cpp of tess-two?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, tesseract, tess-two

we are parsing an image showing a textsnippet which has a resolution of 2121x105 px. In Java we have the following code to get an byte array (one of our constraints is to work with a byte array here):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

...

InputStream is = getAssets().open("images/text.png");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

This byte array is then passed to the native C++ code - we are not using the Java wrapper of tess-two, we use the native libraries though. In the native code we are trying to get the
text of the image with **GetUTF8Text()**. Then we saw that tess-two has already an implementation for setting the image to read from by passing it as a byte array:

```
void Java_com_..._TessBaseAPI_nativeSetImageBytes(JNIEnv *env,
                                                  jobject thiz,
                                                  jlong mNativeData,
                                                  jbyteArray data,
                                                  jint width,
                                                  jint height,
                                                  jint bpp,
                                                  jint bpl) {

...
```

We figured that **bpp** for a PNG should be 4 (RGBA). It's not clear though what is is expected for **bpl**. If we set the width of the image muliplied by **bpp** then we get a segmentation error. If we set it to zero an empty string is returned.

**UPDATE:**
The semgentation error is thrown in **GetUTF8Text()** and not in **SetImage()**.

```
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xc))
```

Comment: You need to decode your png first.

Comment: What do you mean by decode?

Comment: I mean what I said. Your image is encoded with libpng and needs decoding before tesseract can use it. See java example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444869/how-do-i-read-pixels-from-a-png-file)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I get now that I need to decode my jbyteArray, but then I will get another object type while the nativeSetImageBytes expects a byte array. To make it clear the function nativeSetImageBytes is an implementation of tess-two.

Comment: tess-two aka tesseract expects decoded image in rgba rgb or gray format. So you need to decode your png and convert result to byte array. bpp is bytes per pixel for rgba format it would be 4 (1 byte is red 2 is green 3 is blue 4 is alpha) for rgb it would be 3 (1 byte is red 2 is green 3 is blue) for grayscale it would be 1. bpl is bytes per line = bpp * image width

Comment: Would you like to write an answer to my question, so I can assign it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tess-two`](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master/tess-two) which uses [`tesseract OCR`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) expects decoded image in rgba rgb or gray format.

So you need to decode your png ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444869/how-do-i-read-pixels-from-a-png-file) question explains how to do it in java) and convert result to byte array.

***bpp*** is bytes per pixel for rgba format it would be 4 (1 byte is red 2 is green 3 is blue 4 is alpha) for rgb it would be 3 (1 byte is red 2 is green 3 is blue) for grayscale it would be 1.

***bpl*** is bytes per line = bpp * image width